# Create a hash map from an array that returns the largest value

Tags: ruby, hashmap

I have an array of questions where each question has a `category_id` and a `value`.

I'd like to map these so that when the key (`category_id`) already exists in the hash, then the values are added together.

And, finally, I'd like to find the largest value in the hash:

```
h = Hash.new {|k, v| k[v] = 0}  

@test_session.answered_questions.each do |q|

  if h.key?(q.category_id)
     #add q.value to the value stored in the hash
  else
     h = { q.category_id => q.value } #insert the "q.category_id" as key and with value "q.value"
  end        

end

key_with_max_value = h.max_by { |k, v| v }[0] #find the highest value

@result.category = key_with_max_value
@result.score = h[key_with_max_value].value
```

There is probably a lot better way to achieve this but I'm quite new to Ruby.

Comment: `Hash.new(0)` is equivalent to `Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = 0 }` and a lot more concise. The long-form is only required for shared objects like empty arrays and hashes.

Comment: rohit89's answer is good, but just a couple of comments on your own code to keep in find for the future. `h = { q.category_id => q.value }` won't actually insert an entry into an existing hash, it will replace `h` with a new hash containing just the one key. To add an entry to an existing hash you use the `[]` notation. i.e. `h[q.category_id] = q.value`. Also for `@result.score` you don't need the `.value`. `h[key_with_max_value]` would be the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
h = Hash.new(0)
@test_session.answered_questions.each {|q| h[q.category_id] += q.value}
@result.category, @result.score = h.max_by { |k, v| v }
```

Each value in the hash will be initialized to zero with `Hash.new(0)` and since `h.max_by` returns the key value pair, you can directly assign them to your `@result` variable.

Comment: but if i want to add an if statement before the adding like `if q.answer == 1`, how would i do that ? thanks for the answer btw works like a charm :)

Comment: `h[q.category_id] += q.value if q.value == 1` if its just a simple condition. Otherwise you'd have to do it in a `do..end` block like your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
@test_session.answered_questions.each { |q| h[q.category_id] += q.value }
```

When a key is not present, it is assumed to have a value of `0` because of the way you initialized the hash, so it gets inserted with `0 + q.value`.

[See the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html), or try it out.

Also, you can assign two variables separated by commas to `h.max_by { |k, v| v }`. This is called Multiple Assignment, and it works for arrays too:

```
a,b,c = [1,2,3]
```

Comment: wow thats neat but im getting thia syntax error `unexpected tPIPE`

Comment: Sorry, removed the do. Try again as it is now.